# Java - How to get URL array data without external library

Tags: java

I have done data retrieve from given URL in java using below code,

```
 try{
            String id="01";
            //String fullURL="http://XXXX:XXX/XX/getdata/?id="+ id;

        URL u = new URL(fullURL);
            System.out.println(fullURL);
            HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            System.out.println("Message :"+huc.getResponseMessage());
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));

            JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(rd);

            for (Object o : a)
            {
                JSONObject device = (JSONObject) o;

                long kw = (long) device.get("value");
                System.out.println("Sensor value : "+kw);
                //getKw().setKw(kw);

                String ST= (String) device.get("ST");
                System.out.println("Sensor type : "+ST);


                //Timestamp dateTime = (Timestamp) device.get("serverTimeStamp");
                Timestamp dateTime = new Timestamp ((long) device.get("serverTimeStamp"));

                System.out.println("Date in long : "+device.get("serverTimeStamp"));
                System.out.println("Date : "+dateTime);
                //getServerTimeStamp().setServerTimeStamp(dateTime);
                System.out.println("*************");
  }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Actual data is array like below,

```
[
  {

    "value": 777,
    "percentage": 0,
    "serverTimeStamp": 1436900289000,
    "ST": "S"

  },
  {
    "value": 777,
    "percentage": 0,
    "serverTimeStamp": 1436900289000,
    "ST": "V"
  },
  {
    "value": 777,
    "percentage": 0,
    "serverTimeStamp": 1436900289000,
    "ST": "R"
  }
]
```

Its working very fine when i use that json.simple library. but the problem is, I should get the data without using any external library.

How do i achieve this in java code alone?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse JSON without a JSON library? That will be a hard task. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: what is exactly your goal ? you can also copy json source in your code :)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Actualy i have to give this code to client, now they facing difficult to add the external library, so they asking these code without json parser.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina i want to get the array without using json library like while ((inputLine = rd2.readLine()) != null)
            {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine,":");
                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    String value =st.nextToken();
                    System.out.println("value is :"+value);
                }
            }

Comment: Such libraries exist for a good reason: It is a very difficult and error-prone task to manually parse a JSON text (or a XML text or ...). Try to solve the _real problem_ with adding the library. But don't ask on SO for code how to parse JSON without a library.

Comment: perhaps, a simpler problem to resolve is: what is the difficulty for your client to add the external library (for JSON, there is no really need for dependance). Or perhaps there is another library with less difficulty.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina ok i understand you. but why cant we do this without library?

Comment: a library is just code (classes, methods), in another package. absolutely the same as your code, the work to code is equivalent. better copy. Then, 1: if you wand to parse every JSON structure, recode all. 2 If you want only parse your array, try Scanner and regex.

Comment: it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870837/regex-to-find-tokens-java-scanner-or-another-alternative